# Why does indexedDB skip some data when adding to database?

Tags: javascript, json, database, indexeddb, object-storage

I am using javascript to do this.
I want to add data to the database (indexedDB). The data will be coming from the webservice as json and I am looping through it and adding it to an objectStore with a keyPath.

When I look at the data from the webservice, I have an array of 186 objects but when I read the data from indexedDB, I have 151. When I went to check the database to see if the data was there, it wasn't... So something must be going on with my add function.

Here is my code:

Opening a database with an objectStore:

```
let db;
let request = window.indexedDB.open("WHS", 4);

request.onerror = function(event) {
    console.log(event.target.errorCode);
};

request.onsuccess = function(event) {
    db = event.target.result;
};

request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
    let db = event.target.result;
    let palletStore = db.createObjectStore("pallets", { keyPath: "palletno" });
};
```

Adding data after passing it to my function:

```
function addPalletsToIDB(pallets) {
    let transaction = db.transaction(["pallets"], "readwrite");
    let objectStore = transaction.objectStore("pallets");
    $.each(pallets, function(i, pallet) {
        let request = objectStore.put(pallet);
    })
    request.onsuccess = function(event) {
        console.log('Added pallets : ', event.target.response);
    };
    transaction.oncomplete = function() {
        getPalletDataFromIDB();
    }
};
```

Reading the data:

```
function getPalletDataFromIDB() {
    palletsFromIDB = [];
    let transaction = db.transaction(["pallets"], IDBTransaction.READ);
    transaction.oncomplete = function(event) {
        console.log(event);
    };
    transaction.onerror = function(event) {
        console.log(event.type);
    };
    let objectStore = transaction.objectStore("pallets");
    objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
        let cursor = event.target.result;
        if (cursor) {
            palletsFromIDB.push(cursor.value);
            cursor.continue();
        }
        transaction.oncomplete = function() {
            console.log("[palletsFromIDB] ", palletsFromIDB);
            toastr.info("Got pallets");
        };
    };
};
```

from web service : {pallets: Array(186)}
from indexedDB : [palletsFromIDB]  (151)

Comment: Are you sure that the `paletteno` properties on each entry are unique? `put()` will not fail if items with the same key are used - the latest will just overwrite. If this is not expected, you could switch to `add()` which will error (and abort the transaction if `preventDefault()` is not called on the error event)

Comment: This did give me a different result, but the items that weren't being added before still did not get added...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to just create a unique keyPath in your json and making that your keyPath in indexed db.